# Why child process still alive after parent process was killed in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, process

Someone told me that when you killed a parent process in linux, the child would die.
But I doubt it. So I wrote two bash scripts, where `father.sh`would invoke `child.sh`

Here is my script:

[image]

Now I run `bash father.sh`, you could check it `ps -alf`
[image]

Then I killed the `father.sh` by `kill -9 24588`, and I guessed the child process should be terminated but unfortunately I was wrong.
[image]

Could anyone explain why?

thx

Comment: I think that you could cut 80% of the text and all the pictures and still keep everything that matters in this question.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

No, when you kill a process alone, it will not kill the children.

You have to send the signal to the *process group* if you want all processes for a given group to  receive the signal

For example, if your parent process id has the code 1234, you will have to specify the parentpid adding the symbol minus followed by your parent process id:

```
kill -9 -1234
```

Otherwise, orphans will be linked to `init`, as shown by your third screenshot (PPID of the child has become 1).

Comment: Where `thepidhere` is usually the PID of the parent process, but can be found out for sure using `ps -eo "%p %r %c %a"`. +1.

Comment: The process group Id is the same as parent id. Can you give a more detail on how to stop them all

Comment: Just to clarify fge's command in case it is not obvious, you are passing in the parent id as a negative number, e.g. if the parent pid is 1234, you want to kill -1234

Comment: This is not working for me. if I have a process with `PID 123` and I do `kill -9 -123` I have the following error `-bash: kill: (-123) - No such process`. I'm running on Centos 6

Comment: If someone else gets like me `kill: invalid option -- '2'` when running `kill -9 -27541`, just do `kill -9 -- -27541`

Comment: Nowadays please refer to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177361 cause it does not have to be that `orphans will be linked to init`.

Comment: I suggest to rewrite the answer because "-parentpid" seems like an option of the kill command, it's not immediate to think for example kill -9 -1234 if 1234 is the parent process id.

Comment: This answer is incorrect;  the child is not being killed because the father is running sleep, so the father is in kernel mode.  The kernel will not pass down the kill until the kernel finishes its protected execution of father, which sleep is -- literally a noop that is only ended by the timer event and context switch.  However, father has been removed from the active process table and no new signals are recognized.

Answer (score 7):

> -bash: kill: (-123) - No such process

In an interactive Terminal.app session the foreground process group id number and background process group id number are different by design when job control/monitor mode is enabled. In other words, if you background a command in a job-control enabled Terminal.app session, the `$!` pid of the backgrounded process is in fact a new process group id number (pgid).

In a script having no job control enabled, however, this may not be the case! The pid of the backgrounded process may not be a new pgid but a normal pid! And this is, what causes the error message `-bash: kill: (-123) - No such process`, trying to kill a process group but only specifying a normal pid (instead of a pgid) to the `kill` command.

```
# the following code works in Terminal.app because $! == $pgid
{
sleep 100 &
IFS=" " read -r pgid <<EOF
$(ps -p $! -o pgid=)
EOF
echo $$ $! $pgid
sleep 10
kill -HUP -- -$!
#kill -HUP --  -${pgid}  # use in script
}
```

Comment: This answers a **totally different** question

Comment: But actually explained my problem :)

Answer (score 3):

```
pkill -TERM -P <ProcessID>
```

This will kill both Parent as well as child

Comment: Will this also kill processes where the grandparent or great-grandparent matches `ProcessID`?

Comment: @josch No it will kill only the child process but `kill -- -pidnumber` will kill all process tree (child, grandcild, great-grandchild)

Answer (score -3):

Generally killing the parent also kills the child.

The reason that you are seeing the child still alive after killing the father is because the child only will die after it "chooses" (the kernel chooses) to handle the SIGKILL event.  It doesn't have to handle it right away.  Your script is running a sleep() command (i.e. in the kernel), which will not wake up to handle any events whatsoever until the sleep is completed.

Why is PPID #1?  The parent has died and is no longer in the process table.  child.sh isn't *linked* inexplicably to init now.  It simply has no running parent.  Saying it is linked to init creates the impression that if we somehow leave init, that init has control over shutting down the process.  It also creates the impression that killing a parent will make the grandparent the owner of a child.  Both are not true.  That child process still exists in the process table and is running, but no new events based upon it's process ID will be handled until it handles SIGKILL.  Which means that the child is a pre-zombie, walking dead, in danger of being labeled .

Killing in the process group is different, and is used to kill the *siblings*, and the *parent* by the process group #.  It's probably also important to note that "killing a process" is not "killing" per se, in the human way, where you expect the process to be destroyed and all memory returned as though it never was.  It just sends a particular event, among many, to the process for it to handle.  If the process does not handle it properly, then after a while the OS will come along and "clean it up" forcibly.

It (killing) doesn't happen right away because the child (or even the parent) could have written something to disk and be waiting for I/O to complete or doing some other critical task that could compromise system stability or file integrity.

Comment: Beracah, it appears that you just confabulated your entire reply. Accepted answer is correct, and I leave you with this link: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html and quote "The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored."

Comment: Super misleading answer. Killing the parent does *not* generally kill the child. SIGKILL is unignorable. The only reason it might block is if a system call is hung and the process is stuck in kernel mode.

Comment: Yeah, misleading in the way that it is 100% right, and only 90% right if we are being strictly literal about whether execution is currently in kernel mode vs in user mode.  aka, being picky about the word "choose".  Of course, you are right to be picky about the word "choose", as it implies the processes is handling the signal on its own. But the accepted answer is incorrect SPECIFICALLY because father.sh is running *sleep*.    The only way to kill the child then is by killing the group, but killing the group is absolutely a different answer as the processes are separately killed.

Comment: just to clarify, the OPs question literally is, "why wont a child process also get killed while the parent is stuck in kernel mode?"  It isn't phrased that way, but that's what it is.  That's also why the accepted answer is incorrect.  It could lead a different user into killing an entire process group, when only killing the parent was the correct answer.