# Calling bash script from python which kills the python process

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, subprocess

I would like to know whether it possible to launch `bash` script out of `python` in another process, whereas in the `bash` script the is a kill command for the parent python code which gave birth to the bash script?

When the bash script will kill its parent script, will the bash child still be alive?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you just want to kill your process you can use `sys.exit()`

Comment: @Dylan I would say that in most cases if the parent die children become children of the init process.

Comment: The last part of your question has an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533377/why-child-process-still-alive-after-parent-process-was-killed-in-linux

Comment: It is difficult to understand what are you trying to achieve, please try to state it more clearly maybe by showing some code.

Comment: I have a bottle( server) which is running as a process and sometimes I want to update its code.  
Update procedure is sent to the rest api in bottle, this in its turn needs to kill its own process and restart itself

Comment: Since I kill the server it cannot get another command to restart itself, since its down

Comment: So I thought I can launch a new process starting from python which will hold bash that will kill the server and right after that will turn it on back

Comment: Which operating system ...?