# How to kill a spawned "/bin/sh -c" and all its subprocesses using linux syscalls

Tags: linux, signals, system-calls, kill

When I start background processes in a shell using the & operator, if I close the terminal window, all these subprocesses end.

How can I copy this behavior to close an arbitrary process and its children?
For example, if I use the execve syscall to execute this command line :

```
/bin/sh -c "watch ls & watch ls -lah"
```

and I have the PID of the /bin/sh process, I tried to send the SIGHUP signal which should be transmitted to the sons of /bin/sh, but the other processes keep running.

Why aren't the two "watch" processes killed? And is there a way to kill /bin/sh that would also kill them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the kill system call.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>

int kill (pid_t pid, int sig);
```

You should send the SIGKILL signal. 
Regarding killing the child processes, look at [Why child process still alive after parent process was killed in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533377/why-child-process-still-alive-after-parent-process-was-killed-in-linux)

Comment: I already sent the SIGHUP signal using the kill syscall. I also tried to send SIGKILL which didn't kill the sons. Does closing a terminal send SIGHUP or SIGKILL to the process group?