# Will SIGINT and SIGSTOP pause child processes?

Tags: linux, signals, posix, sigint

I am trying to find this in mans but could spot the right man or the right paragraph.

Comment: Question is bit unclear to me but I guess you looked into [man 7 signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

Comment: Re `SIGINT`, [Why child process still alive after parent process was killed in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8533377/608639)

Answer (score 2):

*Will SIGINT and SIGSTOP pause child processes ?* **No**, default action of `SIGINT` is to terminate the process not the pause. While `SIGSTOP` suspends the process & it can be resumes later by `SIGCONT`.

From the manual page of [signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

> ```
> Signal      Standard   Action   Comment
> ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> SIGINT       P1990      Term    Interrupt from keyboard
> SIGSTOP      P1990      Stop    Stop process
> ```

when you send `SIGINT` to a process via `kill()` or by keyboard interrupt, it terminates the process.

However you can modify the default action of certain signals using [sigaction](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) except `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP` as pointed in man page

> The signals `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP` cannot be caught, blocked, or
>          ignored.